# Rentiers in Ancient Greece

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, etymology, ancient-greek

I've been looking for a Greek equivalent of 'Rentiers' who exploit the economy by lobbying the state e.g. asking the state to give them subsidies for a certain common good (climate change) but everything ends up in monopolizing the economy and profit maximization.

In Ancient Greece, "Clereuchy" was a certain form of clientelism where rentiers used to lobby the state to provide lands for poor Greeks for cultivation in new acquired islands to assert dominance over the citizens of these regions & increase their electoral votes.

The term I am looking for is more of an exploitative term that has been described by Aristotle in Politics, book 6, 1360A. However no clear word describes such exploitative behavior in Greek or Ancient Greek. In modern English the word falls under political clientelism.

Comment: "Greek or AG"? Greek signifying Modern Greek? There isn't such a term, as top economists borrow the French [ραντιέρηδες](https://aristosd.wordpress.com/2010/06/) and one only does that in desperation,  in the absence of an AG term, otherwise the Greek chorus would snicker, which oracles avoid at all cost...  Sarcastically, MG uses "κρατοδίαιτος" or something: "eating off the state".

Comment: The Bekker numbering for Politics only goes up to 1342; 1360a is in Rhetoric, and it doesn't seem relevant. (I also don't really agree that "rentier" is the right word in English for the specific phenomenon you describe.)